# Javascript function help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide one div and show another, when a button is clicked.  The button needs to change class after click.

I tried to change these this with `toggleClass` and `toggleSlide`, but it didn't work. Now I just try to show and hide divs onclick. It seems to work somehow, but `removeClass` won't work.

Can somebody understand what's wrong? Or is there better way to do it?

Maybe I can make it with toggle array or something, that simplifies the code or click counts (`if count c++%2!=2`), don't even know if that's possible.

```
$('div.more-lang').hide();
$('div.lang-arrow').click(function () {
    $('div.lang-arrow').addClass('more');
    $('#lang').hide('');
    $('div.more-lang').show('');
});

$('div.lang-arrow.more').click(function () {
    $('div.lang-arrow').removeClass('more');
    $('div.more-lang').hide('');
    $('#lang').show('');
});
```

Comment: I think you should check out toggleClass in the jQuery docs

Comment: Why are you passing a blank string (`''`) to `.hide` and `.show`?

Comment: Here is a fiddle to demonstrate how to use `.toggleClass` http://jsfiddle.net/2j9JG/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("div.lang-arrow").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("more");
    $("#lang").toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zmvQp/

Comment: It worked. Thanks! But can you explain me, what is the difference " .on('click') and .onclick?

Comment: there is no functional difference, `.click(function(..` calls `.on('click', function(..`, I like to use a few more letters but drop the extra function call